# getting error SQLCODE=-10, SQLSTATE=42603, SQLERRMC='),

Tags: sql, database, db2

performing following query in java script

```
String sql = "insert into personal values('"+models.getResourceId()+"','"+models.getFname()+"','"+models.getMname()+"','"+models.getLname()+"','"+models.getGender()+"','"+models.getDob()+"','"+models.getFthname()+"','"+models.getEmail()+"','"+models.getMobile_no()+"')";
```

i don't know what to correct.

**the query is in DB2**

Comment: Surely you mean Java and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use parameter binding. Give us the whole sql after you put it together. You likely used a  `'` in one of the other variables and didn't escape that one.

Are you sure that you are using javascript for accessing the database? I'm not aware of such a driver/possiblity. And it would be new to me that javascript knows types like `String`.

Comment: To escape a `'` in DB2, it needs to be doubled up: `''`. Edit: But of course, it's much better to use parameter binding and let the DB2 driver take care of this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, just saved my day!!

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation,  "The statement contains a string constant that is not terminated properly" Please follow http://lasanthals.blogspot.com/2012/09/db2-error-codes.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The input value contains may contains single quotes inside, ex: 'RPG's'